# How can you use "getAttribute" method of WebDriver in HTML structure?

Tags: selenium

How can you use "getAttribute" method of WebDriver for the given HTML structure?

```
<span id=“span1”  class=“spanClass” > Option1 </span>
```

Code trials  :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("span1")).getAttribute("class");
```

and

```
driver.findElement.getAttribute(By.id("span1"));
```

and

```
driver.findElement("value").getAttribute(By.id("span1"));
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.id("span1")).getAttribute();
```

Answer (score 0):

**your first trial,**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("span1")).getAttribute("class");
```

looks good, did you try **printing** that ? if yes, did you get proper output or was there any other error ?

your **2nd code trial**

```
driver.findElement.getAttribute(By.id("span1"));
```

is invalid, since you can not call `getAttribute()` like that, it should result in **compile time error.**

Your **3rd code trial :**

```
driver.findElement("value").getAttribute(By.id("span1"));
```

is again `invalid`, **you can not find the element with a string input.**

**your 4th code trial :**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("span1")).getAttribute();
```

is again invalid, since you are not passing anything in `getAttribute();`

method. It should again result in compile time error.

Below is an alternative way with xpath  :

```
//span[@id='span1']
```

and get the `id` or `class` attribute like this  :

```
String idAttribute = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='span1']")).getAttribute("id");
System.out.println(idAttribute)
```

or to get class `attribute` you can do something like this  :

```
String classAttribute = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='span1']")).getAttribute("class");
    System.out.println(idAttribute)
```